# flask routes not working on gae application

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask

I have the following directory structure for my GAE project:

- endpoints/

  - insights/

    - insights.py
    - init.py
- lib/

  - __init__.py
- insights.yaml

so in order to get access to the third libraries within lib folder I add the next code in __init__.py file.

```
import os
import sys


def add_lib_path():
    lib_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    if lib_directory not in sys.path:
       sys.path.insert(0, lib_directory)
```

and I added this code in the insights.py file before the import statements:

```
from lib import add_lib_path
add_lib_path()
```

the problem is that now I can import third libraries correctly but my `@app.route('/something', methods=['POST'])` are not working.

I send a post request and it returns status 200 but it doesn't go inside my @app.route code, I can actually send any route and it just pass out returning 200 but not data and not error.

My imports look like this:

```
from lib import add_lib_path
add_lib_path()
from flask import Flask, request
```

And my code inside @app.route('/something', methods=['POST']) looks like this:

```
def someDef():
    some code ...

    return response
```

my yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
service: insights

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: endpoints/insights/insights.py

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Any suggestions about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough info.  Need to see your `app.yaml` and perhaps `urls.py`.

Comment: @GAEfan I just updated with my yaml file code, btw what you mean with urls.py?, I don't have that file

Comment: By default, the app will be looking for a file called `app.yaml`.  You can name it `insights.yaml`, but you must tell the app that is the name to look for.  Add some logging.  Try changing the name to `app.yaml`, and deleting the `service: insights` line, to make sure you are in default configuration.

Comment: im working with more than one handler, I have my app.yaml for application.py that is in the root and insights.yaml for my insights.py file, what Im trying is not to have everything in the root folder, so
In my app.yaml I have this handler `handlers: - url: /.*  script: application.app` , how can I add an handler for my insights file? I try this: `handlers: - url: /.*  script: endpoints/insights/insights.py`, so I change `threadsafe` from `true` to `false` but its not working, how can I connect this to my insights.py file in order to have just one yaml file?

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question.  See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard URL handler in your `app.yaml` is intercepting the `/something` post:

```
handlers: 
- url: /.* 
  script: application.app
```

You will need to either map out individual urls in your app, or make unique url set for your `insights`, like `/insights/.*` in `app.yaml`.  Either way, you can't have a catch-all url handler in your `app.yaml` if there are other urls you want to give special treatment to, like sending to a separate service.

Comment: great thank you, now I'm getting into the insights.py from app.yaml, this is my app.yaml file:


`runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
service: default

handlers:
- url: /app/.*
  script: application.py

- url: /insights/.*
  script: endpoints/insights/insights.py

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest`


now the problem is that it is "jumping" my `@app.route('/ages', methods=['POST'])`, I added some logging and it is reading this file but not my flask's decorators

Answer (score 0):

ok I just changed in the app.yaml file the `threadsafe to true`, then I added the script like this `endpoints.insights.insights.app`, using Python module path (**with dots not *slash***) and in my insights.py file I changed `@app.route('/something', methods=['POST'])` to `@app.route('/insights/something', methods=['POST'])` .. I added the complete URL that I defined in the app.yaml file and now it's working.

Thanks to @GAEfan for the help, I'll accept the *GAEfan* answer because it helped me a lot